# All files vanish in /home/user directory Ubuntu 20.04 (dual boot with Windows 11)

Tags: data-loss

I recently had a bug in Ubuntu 20.04

- all files vanished or deleted in /home/user, except the directories where kept in place
- Logged out of my Google/Microsoft accounts, so I had to sign in again after restarting
- Terminal user color changed from green to white (reinstalling gnome-terminal didn't help!), see image:
  [image: Green to white in terminal]
- all installed applications remain intact

Does anyone have any ideas about this? I would be happy to provide more information, for example log-files etc, but for the moment I don't know where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you do before that happened?

Comment: The very last thing was installing ClamAV. However, I recently updated the kernel from 5.13 to 5.14.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I also upgraded Windows from 10 to 11 in the Windows partition.